# Tuning of a Web handler regex routes configuration

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, web-applications, routes

In a web handler routes configuration I have the following Regex:

```
('/post/(\w+)/.*', foo.app.WebHandlerFooClass)
```

this regex matches these kind of urls:

- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH/this-is-the-slug`
- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH/`

passing the correct `HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH` *Id* parameter to the web handler matched by the `(\w+)` group.

How could I modify the above Regex to match also this url?

```
/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH
```

The handler is coded to accept just one parameter, the base64 Id, so **there should be just one group in the Regex** that matches the Id.

So, these are the urls that should be matched:

- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH/this-is-the-slug`
- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH/`
- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH` <-- Hey, I wanna this too

Comment: Meaning the id and optional slash or id + slug and optional slash?

Comment: id and optional slash. The slash at the end of the slug is not a problem right now because it is swallowed by the `.*`

Comment: Are you looking to *fix* that, as it seems like a poor implementation? Also, is this a separate route or the same? Might be good to share the underlying technology too.

Comment: Why poor implementation? Should be the same route.

Comment: One big caveat in doing this: Relative URLs will be different depending on if the URL ends with a `/` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'/post/(\w+_-)(?:/([\w-]+))?/?'
```

This matches the following.

- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH/this-is-the-slug`
- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH/this-is-the-slug/`
- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH/`
- `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH`

I think this is a *better* implementation because it captures only the pieces you want, e.g. the slug doesn't capture a trailing `/`. However, your spec is still slightly unclear to me, so this may not be your intention.

Comment: The handler is coded to accept just one parameter, the Id, so there should be just one group in the regex that matches the Id.

Comment: Since you didn't provide your technology I have no idea of such constraints. The regular expression I provided works for the spec.

Comment: if you want to drop the slug on the floor, make the slug group a non-capturing group; use `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`

Comment: @Jason I've modified the code, with your solution I can match the GET to the urls without slug redirecting properly to the canonical url.

Answer (score 1):

If I guessed right your real intention, then you are fine with this one:

```
'/post/(\w+)'
```

Comment: No, that matches id and slug all togheter.

Comment: No it does not, or give me countraexample. \w would notmatch forward slash. If you give /post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH/this-is-the-slug/ to this than you get HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH in $1 which is probably what you want.

Comment: with a little bit more of lucidity I've tried you solution and I'm sorry to say that it does not work. Why? Your solution works just with the third link `/post/HUIHUIGgS823SHUIH` and obviously not with the first two.

Comment: this is really strange. try this one: '/post/(\w+).*' (should be equivalent to the posted one

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the data at the end, then why not just use this?

```
'/post/(\w+).*'
```

Otherwise you'll have to provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

```
'/post/([^/]+).*'
```

But that seems too simple an answer :)